# Addition using Dictionary updates

Tags: python

I have a bunch of dicts such as ...

```
{u'APPLES': 1}
{u'PEARS': 7}
{u'BANANAS': 10}

{u'APPLES': 9}
{u'PEARS': 13}
{u'BANANAS': 20}
```

However I want to add them together so i end up with `{"APPLES":10}` etc. What is the best pythonic way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: What form is the data in? Is it `{u'APPLES': 1, u'PEARS': 7, ... }` or `[{u'APPLES': 1}, {u'PEARS': 7}, ... ]`?

Comment: It's a little disappointing that the OP on that question chose the answer he did rather than DiggyF's answer (which is identical to mine… and even has the unnecessary `reduce` alternative), but yeah, it's a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

for d in bunch_of_dicts:
    counts.update(d)
```

Comment: `Counter.update` would be more concise.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

totals = collections.Counter()
for d in a_bunch_of_dicts:
    totals.update(d)
```

Comment: I'm surprised it's been 2 minutes and there's still nobody suggesting `reduce` leading to an argument about whether every `reduce` is better as an explicit loop or not. :)